# Show that $(S^n \times S^n) \setminus \{p\}$ is not contractible

Tags: differential-topology, homotopy-theory

> Show that
>
> 1. $\mathbb{R}^n$ is contractible.
> 2. $(S^n \times S^n) \setminus \{p \}$ is not contractible.

For (1) define $F:\mathbb{R}^n \times I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ by $F(x,t)=tx$ then $F(x,1)=1x=x=Id$ and $F(x,0)=0x=0$ and therefore $Id$ is homotopic to the constant function $0$ hence $\mathbb{R^n}$ is contractible.

For (2) I try to show that $\{p\} \times S^n \subset S^n \times S^n$ is not contractible in $S^n \times S^n$ but $\{p\} \times S^{n}$ is contractible is $S^{2n}$

Any hint or help i will be very grateful.
Any hint or help i will be very grateful

Comment: It is difficult to answer because we don't know what you know — the first item is really trivial (probably the very first example one sees of a contractible space) while the second one requires technology one encounter considerably later.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez What technology is this, exactly? I have a low level knowledge of algebraic topology. I know the homotopy groups are trivial in contractible spaces, so perhaps you are referring to a high-tech way of calculating the (higher) homotopy groups of $(S^n\times S^n)\setminus\{p\}$?

Comment: Assuming you know that $S^n$ is not contractible: if $(S^n \times S^n) \setminus \{ p \}$ were contractible, then you could take some slice of the product avoiding $p$, compose the contraction with the projection onto $S^n$, and get a contraction of $S^n$, resulting in a contradiction.

Comment: @FShrike I was imagining the commenter might have in mind a calculation using the Mayer-Vietoris sequence and the Kunneth formula to calculate the (co)homology groups, by covering the space by $(S^n \setminus \{ p_1 \}) \times S^n$ and $S^n \times (S^n \setminus \{ p_2 \})$.  (Though I guess the Kunneth formula part of that isn't strictly needed, if you observe that each is homotopy equivalent to $S^n$ since $S^n$ minus a point is contractible.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler Right... completely over my head for now! But your first comment makes good sense to me

Comment: @FShrike, well, any technology allowing you to show that S^n is not contractible — homology, higher homotopy groups, … My point is that it is a weird combination of problems because anyone who knows how to compute $\pi_n(S^n)$, say, has seen that $\mathbb R^n$ is contractible quite a long time ago!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Ok, thank you for responding!

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment

...

For $n=1$. I can see intiutively that $S^1\times S^1-\{p\}$, which is a torus with a deleted point, is homotopic to $S^1\lor S^1$ which is a figure-$8$ on $\Bbb{R}^2$. I found a problem set about these topics: [https://web.physics.utah.edu/~lake/math/exercises_in_alg_top.pdf](https://web.physics.utah.edu/%7Elake/math/exercises_in_alg_top.pdf)

I think for $n\geq 2$, it can be generalized, not sure but maybe $S^n\times S^n-\{p\}\sim S^n\lor S^n$ and it is not contractible.

I found this **picture web** site: https://www.math3ma.com/blog/clever-homotopy-equivalences about these kind of problems... It gives some ideas about deformations which are really hard to vizualize.

Some ideas:

$\begin{align}
S^n\times S^n-p &= S^n\times S^n-(p_1,p_2)\\
&=(S^n-p_1\times S^n)\cup (S^n\times S^n-p_2)\\
&\text{I thought now sphere deleted a point is homotopic to a point.}\\
&\simeq(p_2\times S^n)\cup (S^n\times p_1) \\
&\simeq S^n\lor S^n\\
\end{align}$